# How to secure more my md5 password encoding in PHP

Tags: php, hash, cryptography, passwords, md5

I am seeking some suggestion to secure my password encoding. Here I wanted to mention that I don't want to use new password_hash() api and also dont want to migration of old password, If I used password_hash() api , I have to migrate my old user password, which is not gong to possible for now. SO here is my old approach.

```
function login() {
//the code of getting password from database.......I am skipping this part.....
if(!Check($given_pass,$expected_pass)))  
    //User enter a password in the session as given_pass and expected_pass is the md5 generated hash password stored in database.
    return error('pass error');
return notice('pass success');
}

function Encode($text) {
    return md5(paramtr2Str("conf.cryptographykey").$text);  
    //cryptography key is a random generated string at the server side.
}

function Check($given_pass, $expected_pass) {
    return $expected == Encode($given_pass);
}
```

I think my Encode function is hackable and I want to give it some extra security by sticking with the original formatting.

Comment: IDK much, but I know md5 can be 'spoofed'. For starters you may wish to upgrade your hashing algorithm

Comment: What do you mean by "hackable"?  Let's be clear; MD5 is not cryptographically secure.  If you want a secure system, a prerequisite is to not use MD5.

Comment: Best way to secure your md5, stip using md5 and start using password_hash() even if you don't want to.... asking people how you can secure a system while telling them you won't accept the best advice available isn't a particularly sensible approach to asking for help

Comment: 256 bits *or nothing*!  Well when quantum computing really kicks off we're all boned but in the meantime choose life. choose 256 bits+

Comment: I know password_hash() is more secure.. But because of some limitation I can not migrate the system now.. May be later gradually I will migrate..But for now I need a temporal solution..

Comment: what about `sha1` applied on the current hashed passwords? then you need to use `sha1(md5(...))` to get the saved hash.

Comment: If you can't change the system to use password_hash(), because you can't reset existing user passwords, then you'll have problems changing anything anyway.... solution is to force them to go through a reset password screen the next time they login, and use password_hash() with their new passwords

Comment: If you can't use password_hash() because you're running too early a version of PHP to use even the userland compatibility version, then you really should be upgrading PHP anyway, because you're running a version that's no longer supported

Comment: My Server version is PHP 5.5 .. I did not want to use password_hash() because now I did not want to force user to reset their password.. Is their anyway to update old md5 password by not forcing them to reset their password?

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the MD5 encrypted password with `sha1()`. You have to encrypt all users passwords (MD5 encrypted) with `sha1()` again in your database and in the login page check their password with this `sha1(md5($password))` and compare it with you database.

This will improve your site security quite lot but I'd recommend you to use [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) anyway.

Comment: password_hash() used for PHP >= 5.5.0

Comment: Everything's right. This is definition to your post. Is it wrong definition? For example my hosting plan's PHP 5.4.31. Can I use password_hash()?